# why I cannot fetch related fields on my prisma query with my GO client?

Tags: go, graphql, prisma

I am very very new in Prisma but so far I managed to do queries and map it using graphql, but then I noticed that I was not fetching the whole information.

Here is what I have.

I have a table called Highlight

The table has a relation to HighlightItems  (that is a wrapper to fetch a postId, number of votes , etc, etc)

so I mapped my prisma objects and seem to be working...

I have this in my datamodel.prisma

```
type Highlight {
    id: UUID! @id
    highlightId: String! @unique
    createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
    highlightItems: [HighlightItem!]! 
      @relation(
        link: TABLE
        name: "HighlightItemByHighlight"
        onDelete: CASCADE
      )
```

and at my HighlightItem

```
type HighlightItem {
    id: UUID! @id
    createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
    lastComment: String ....
```

I was able to generate the prisma model and use the generated mutations:

```
mutation {
  createHighlight(....
```

and I am able to query directly the prismadb with the queries:

```
query {
  highlights{
    highlightId, highlightItems{id}
  }
}
```

Now I have the issue when working with my GO resolver

when I do this:

```
func (r *queryResolver) Highlights(ctx context.Context, first, last *int, before, after, search *string, input string, input2 string ) (*models.Highlights, error) {


    allHighligts, err := prisma.Instance.Highlights(
        &prisma.HighlightsParams{

        }).Exec(ctx)
       ....
```

Then I realize that I cannot get the `HighlightItems` **through** Highlight, checked the document on the prisma client for GO and it should use the `"fluent API"`

https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-GO-go05/#relations

but so far I am not able to fetch them, any idea what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be about capitalize variable names. Can you do uppercase first letter of variables?

Comment: what do you mean by uppercase the variable? the allHighlights var??

Comment: No, I mean models as `type HighlightItem {
    Id: UUID! @id
    CreatedAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    UpdatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
    LastComment: String ....`